# Shortening a repetitive expression in r

Tags: r, estimation, mle

I have a system of equations that is being estimated jointly in maximum likelihood in r. There are three equations in the system, with two being structural (coefficients estimated start with `b` and `c`) and one first stage (`g`). The controls are uniform in the three equations `(x1,x4,x5,x6,x8,x8,x10,x11,x12,x13,x17,x18,19,x20,x21,x25,x27,d2,d3,d5,d6,d7,d8d,d9,d10,d11)` with the addition of three instrument `(x22,x23,x24)` in expression for `g`. All the expressions starting with `x` are data points.
Due to the repetitive nature of the expressions, I keep making mistakes when manually type them in. Could someone recommend an efficient way of writing this function?

My loglikelihood function is as follows

```
ll6 <- function(param){
  
  b0  <- param[1]
  b1  <- param[2]
  b4  <- param[3]
  b5  <- param[4]
  b6  <- param[5]
  b8  <- param[6]
  b9  <- param[7]
  b10 <- param[8]
  b11 <- param[9]
  b12 <- param[10]
  b13 <- param[11]
  b15 <- param[12]
  b17 <- param[13]
  b18 <- param[14]
  b19 <- param[15]
  b20 <- param[16]
  b21 <- param[17]
  b25 <- param[18]
  b27 <- param[19]
  
  g0  <- param[20]
  g1  <- param[21]
  g4  <- param[22]
  g5  <- param[23]
  g6  <- param[24]
  g8  <- param[25]
  g9  <- param[26]
  g10 <- param[27]
  g11 <- param[28]
  g12 <- param[29]
  g13 <- param[30]
  g17 <- param[31]
  g18 <- param[32]
  g19 <- param[33]
  g20 <- param[34]
  g21 <- param[35]
  g22 <- param[36]
  g23 <- param[37]
  g24 <- param[38]
  g25 <- param[39]
  g27 <- param[40]
  
  
  c0  <- param[41]
  c1  <- param[42]
  c4  <- param[43]
  c5  <- param[44]
  c6  <- param[45]
  c8  <- param[46]
  c9  <- param[47]
  c10 <- param[48]
  c11 <- param[49]
  c12 <- param[50]
  c13 <- param[51]
  c15 <- param[52]
  c17 <- param[53]
  c18 <- param[54]
  c19 <- param[55]
  c20 <- param[56]
  c21 <- param[57]
  c25 <- param[58]
  c27 <- param[59]
  
  
  bl2 <- param[60]
  bl3 <- param[61]
  bl5 <- param[62]
  bl6 <- param[63]
  bl7 <- param[64]
  bl8 <- param[65]
  bl9 <- param[66]
  bl10<- param[67]
  bl11<- param[68]
  
  cl2 <- param[69]
  cl3 <- param[70]
  cl5 <- param[71]
  cl6 <- param[72]
  cl7 <- param[73]
  cl8 <- param[74]
  cl9 <- param[75]
  cl10<- param[76]
  cl11<- param[77]
  
  gl2 <- param[78]
  gl3 <- param[79]
  gl5 <- param[80]
  gl6 <- param[81]
  gl7 <- param[82]
  gl8 <- param[83]
  gl9 <- param[84]
  gl10<- param[85]
  gl11<- param[86]
  
  sum(log(
    ((pnorm(b0+b1*x1+ b4*x4+ b5*x5+ b6*x6+ b8*x8+
                  b9*x9+ b10*x10+b11*x11+ b12*x12+ b13*x13+b15*x15+b17*x17+b18*x18
                +b19*x19+b20*x20+b21*x21+b25*x25+b27*x27+ bl2*d2 + bl3*d3 + bl5*d5 + bl6*d6 + bl7*d7 + 
                  bl8*d8 + bl9*d9 + bl10*d10 + bl11*d11))^y)
    * ((pnorm(g0 + g1*x1 + g4*x4+ g5*x5+ g6*x6+g8*x8+g9*x9+ g10*x10
                    +g11*x11+ g12*x12+ g13*x13+g17*x17+g18*x18+g19*x19+g20*x20+g21*x21+
                      g25*x25+g27*x27+g22*z1+g23*z2+g24*z3+ gl2*d2 + gl3*d3 + gl5*d5 + gl6*d6 + gl7*d7 + 
                      gl8*d8 + gl9*d9 + gl10*d10 + gl11*d11))^x15)
    *((pnorm(c0+c1*x1+ c4*x4+ c5*x5+ c6*x6+c8*x8+
                     c9*x9+ c10*x10+c11*x11+ c12*x12+ c13*x13+c15*x15+c17*x17+c18*x18
                   +c19*x19+c20*x20+c21*x21+c25*x25+c27*x27+ cl2*d2 + cl3*d3 + cl5*d5 + cl6*d6 + cl7*d7 + 
                     cl8*d8 + cl9*d9 + cl10*d10 + cl11*d11))^x14)
    * ((1-pnorm(b0+b1*x1+ b4*x4+ b5*x5+ b6*x6+ b8*x8+
                          b9*x9+ b10*x10+b11*x11+ b12*x12+ b13*x13+b15*x15+b17*x17+b18*x18
                        +b19*x19+b20*x20+b21*x21+b25*x25+b27*x27+  bl2*d2 + bl3*d3 + bl5*d5 + bl6*d6 + bl7*d7 + 
                          bl8*d8 + bl9*d9 + bl10*d10 + bl11*d11))^(1-y))
    *((1-pnorm(g0 + g1*x1 + g4*x4+ g5*x5+ g6*x6+g8*x8+g9*x9+ g10*x10
                         +g11*x11+ g12*x12+ g13*x13+g17*x17+g18*x18+g19*x19+g20*x20+g21*x21+g25*x25+g27*x27
                         +g22*z1+g23*z2+g24*z3+ gl2*d2 + gl3*d3 + gl5*d5 + gl6*d6 + gl7*d7 + 
                           gl8*d8 + gl9*d9 + gl10*d10 + gl11*d11))^(1-x15))
    * ((1-pnorm(c0+c1*x1+ c4*x4+ c5*x5+ c6*x6+c8*x8+
                            c9*x9+ c10*x10+c11*x11+ c12*x12+ c13*x13+c15*x15+c17*x17+c18*x18
                          +c19*x19+c20*x20+c21*x21+c25*x25+c27*x27+ cl2*d2 + cl3*d3 + cl5*d5 + cl6*d6 + cl7*d7 + 
                            cl8*d8 + cl9*d9 + cl10*d10 + cl11*d11))^(1-x14)) ))
  
  
}
```

I tried saving the parts of expressions separately as follows but keep getting an error with the addition to maxLik command not running.

```
    da<-b0+b1*x1+ b4*x4+ b5*x5+ b6*x6+ b8*x8+
      b9*x9+ b10*x10+b11*x11+ b12*x12+ b13*x13+b15*x15+b17*x17+b18*x18
    +b19*x19+b20*x20+b21*x21+b25*x25+b27*x27+ bl2*d2 + bl3*d3 + bl5*d5 + bl6*d6 + bl7*d7 + 
      bl8*d8 + bl9*d9 + bl10*d10 + bl11*d11
Error: object 'b0' not found
```

Comment: It's hard to say because I'm not sure on how you are assigning variables, but a tip - you can dynamically assign a variable using like this ``assign(paste0("b", i), param[i+1])``. Can you clarify exactly the rules you have to assign variables?

Comment: Also - I have just seen the summing of the log likelihoods! I think you need to explain what's going on there before anyone can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, made edits for clarity. Let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: Funny enough, in times when I can't avoid having something like this in code for some reason, I have jumped to Excel and written some concatenate functions and then copied/pasted back in. I find it silly, but hey, it works.

Comment: Thanks Adam. I do that when I export tables to latex from r but never r code will definitely try that.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a named list and the expand this to the environment with `list2env`. For example, here's how to reduce the code for the `f` variabels

```
vidx <- c(0,1,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26)
vnames <- paste0("g", vidx)
pidx <- 20:(20+length(vidx)-1)

list2env(setNames(as.list(params[pidx]), vnames), envir=globalenv())
```

This will create all the `g*` values in one go. You can so this for the other variables as well.